Spikes in Loss During Training both train/val datasets with LSTM
I'm seeing good results I think, but I want to understand why these spikes in loss are occuring.

As you can see, it would appear that my training is working as it should, but every 200 or so epochs the loss spikes but then continues on trajectory. What would be the cause of this? Is it just stepping out of minima but if that were true wouldn't I see a smoothing of loss rate before the spike? Below is my code.
class CustomModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.lstm1 = torch.nn.LSTM(input_size=11, hidden_size=768, num_layers=1, batch_first=True)
        self.lstm2 = torch.nn.LSTM(input_size=768, hidden_size=256, num_layers=1, batch_first=True)
        self.fc = torch.nn.Linear(256, 1)

    def forward(self, x):
        x,_ = self.lstm1(x)
        x,_ = self.lstm2(x)
        x = self.fc(x)
        return x

optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.001, amsgrad=True)

criterion = nn.HuberLoss()

